# Generate Unique Id for client server authentication

Tags: java, mysql, uniqueidentifier

I'm creating an app where in, a client sends a request to the server and in turn gets a unique request id. This unique request id would be used later authenticate the client when it wants to interact again with the server.

The request of client are of two types:

1. New request, where it has no existing id and the response from the
   server generates and returns an id.
2. Existing request with the id. The server then processes the clients
   request for the id supplied.

My problem is how do I generate the id? I'm using Java and MySQL server database. If I use an auto-incremented database generated id, then it becomes too easy for the client to guess the ids. Another client could maliciously generate a few ids by guessing and misuse them (There is no authentication between the client/sever, except for the ids :< )

If I generate a random id using UUID or some other randomize algorithm, then I need to check the entire database (which could have thousands of records), to really check and guarantee if the random id is unique indeed? Or would it be fast inside the database to check if the id exits and won't cause performance issues?

What measures should I take? Do I need to have more security measures for authentication between the client and the server, other than the unique id?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581828/623041

Comment: You never have to 'check an entire database'. You would have to check one table, and it should have an index on the column you are checking for.

Comment: @EJP: I meant the same - checking the entire column for a duplicate value. However, the table could have few thousands of values hence the concern for performance. I'll edit the question though :)

Comment: 'Checking the entire column' is just an index lookup, provided the column is indexed. Even if it has a million entries its performance is not a concern.

Comment: Well that was something I dint know earlier (haven't used databases extensively) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `java.util.UUID.randomUUID();` you can generate a cryptographically secure, random UUID.

Since the UUID is 128 bit long, the chance for a collision is negligible, but if you really want to check for collisions, you can do that by storing active UUIDs in the database and check for duplicates after generation.

Answer (score 2):

Create an encoded and unique *key* for each session,  that will be created using the unique data you have of that user, something like his email, current time, etc.

```
String yourString = "user@email.com"+"timestamp"; 
byte[] bytesOfMessage = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
```

Would generate a unique id for each request, store them in a table in your database that contains an expiry timestamp, userid and the key. The on each request, renew the "expiry" time if its still valid, or return error if its expired or invalid.

The valid keys table I use is something like:

```
userId(int)
key(varchar(32))
expiry(int)
```

Then if you wanted to see if a user has a valid session open you'd just check that table for the `userId` and make sure that it's a unique column, to avoid storing a historic of previous sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's UUID.
Something like :

```
UUID uniqueKey = UUID.randomUUID();
```

And if you don't wanna use that, you can use the time, as it is always changing, add a random number if u wanna be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Spring Framework** you may found useful another UUID implementation `org.springframework.util.AlternativeJdkIdGenerator`:

```
IdGenerator generator = new AlternativeJdkIdGenerator();
UUID uuid = generator.generateId();
```

Which is from the documentation:

> An {@link IdGenerator} that uses {@link SecureRandom} for the initial
>   seed and  * {@link Random} thereafter, instead of calling {@link
>   UUID#randomUUID()} every  * time as {@link
>   org.springframework.util.JdkIdGenerator JdkIdGenerator} does.  * This
>   provides a better balance between securely random ids and performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you 'd like to generate it on MySQL side, I think this will do just fine

```
md5(concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),<user_id>))
```

If the field is indexed, query won't take long.

Comment: Knowing the implementation, it would still be fairly easy for a malicious client to guess valid ids.

Comment: Guess you're right, I only took uniqueness into account. Thus, UUID or (salt-)hashed UUID is a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a UUID to generate a base ID that is nearly always unique.
2. Hash the base ID to make it difficult for clients to guess and spoof.
3. Store the hashed ID in the database using a column with a unique constraint.
4. On the rare occasion the unique constraint is violated, repeat the above steps.